# Can you programatically detect text colors in an excel doc and modify only cells with text of a specific color and font style?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a requirement where an excel document needs to be scrubbed based on multiple rules; one of those is to programatically delete all cells with red text and strikethrough font style in a given column. Once you access your excel doc in C# using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library, is there a way to detect what color a cell's text is and font style applied, and delete the cell if its text is red with strikethrough style?

```
public static void GetExcelFile() {
        //Establish COM Objects
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"\MyExcelBook.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheet[1];
        Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        //Retrieve Column E
        object[] columnE = excelWorkSheet.Range["E"].Values2;

        //Scrub Column E
        //Remove expired codes (signified by red font and strikethrough)

        //Remove  Whitespace
        string trColumnE = columnE.ToString();
        string[] strColumnE = trColumnE.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
```

Comment: The short answer, yes you can detect and even modify the cell.  But to create conditional logic to account for a lot of what you speak, will be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before retrieving you can check like below:

```
 if (excelWorkSheet.Range["E"].Font.Strikethrough == true && excelWorkSheet.Range["E"].Interior.Color = 255)
            excelWorkSheet.Range["E"].Value == "";
```